# Let $x, y \in \mathbb R$ such that $x^2+y^2=2x-2y+2$. Find the largest possible value of $x^2+y^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, contest-math, maxima-minima

> Let $x, y \in \mathbb R$ s. t . $x^2+y^2=2x-2y+2$.  Find the largest possible value of $x^2+y^2-\sqrt{32}$

I know this is a [duplicate of another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3618662/721644), but that question has solutions involving calculus and geometry, while I want a solution **relying on algebra and basic inequalities only** to solve this problem.

Comment: @ SM Sheikh I only want algebraic solutions

Comment: Sujal, I high-lighted the _pure algebraic solution_ request and linked the post that already has answers (as you 've already mentioned), so the community members can see what methods were used there and how they differ from what you're looking for, no matter if it's sufficient, but at least we could eliminate this and that after trying the _algebraic_ method. I hope people will read it. Good night if it's night in your time-zone!

Answer (score 5):

You can rearrange the equation into the form
$$(x-1)^2+(y+1)^2=r^2$$
for some constant $r$ which I will let you find for yourself. This is a circle with centre $(1,-1)$ and radius $r$, so obviously its furthest distance from the origin is $r+\sqrt 2$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $ z=x+iy$. Then, we have $ |z-(1+i)| =2$ from $x^2+y^2=2x-2y+2$, and

$$|z|= |z-(1+i)+(1+i )| \le | z-(1+i)|+ |1+i |= 2+ \sqrt 2=|z|_{max}$$

Thus, the largest possible value is

$$x^2+y^2= |z|_{max}^2 = (2+\sqrt 2)^2=6+4\sqrt2$$

Answer (score 2):

We have: $$6+ \underbrace{\left( 1+\frac{\,\sqrt {2}}{2} \right)  \left( {x}^{2}+{y}^{2}-2\,x+2\,y-2
 \right)}_{=\, 0} -({x}^{2}+{y}^{2}-\sqrt {32})$$
$$=\frac{\,\sqrt {2}}{4} \left( \sqrt {2}\,x-\sqrt {2}-2 \right) ^{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\,
 \left( \sqrt {2}y+\sqrt {2}+2 \right) ^{2}\geqq 0$$
Therefore: $$x^2 +y^2 -\sqrt{32} \leqq 6$$

> Use this useful identity: $$ax^2 +bx+c =a(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2 +\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}$$

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach: Let $S=\{(x,y) : x^2+y^2=2x-2y+2\}$ be the algebraic curve of the constraint and let $A=\{(x,y): x+y=0\}$ be the anti-diagonal. We have the basic inequality: $(x-y)^2 \leq 2(x^2+y^2)$ with equality iff $(x,y)\in A$. Thus, for points in $S$ we have:
  $$ (x-y)^2 \leq 4(x-y) + 4 $$
with equality iff $(x,y)\in A$ (in addition to being in $S$).
Equivalently,  $(x-y-2)^2 \leq 8$ or $2-2\sqrt{2} \leq x-y \leq 2+2\sqrt{2}$, with the two extremal cases corresponding to $S\cap A$. Evaluating on $S$ we get the upper bound:
  $$ x^2+y^2 -\sqrt{32} \leq 2(2+2\sqrt{2}) + 2 - 4\sqrt{2} = 6$$
with equality  being attained at the unique intersection of $x-y=2+2\sqrt{2}$ and $x+y=0$, i.e. $x=-y=1+\sqrt{2}$